# C's coverage of assembly

Tags: c, assembly, compilation

In an argument with a friend, I made the remark that it is impossible to write, in any language besides C, a program that is faster than *all* variants in C, that do the same thing.  My argument was based on an affirmative answer to the question below.  Is it true?

- If we think of "compiling" as a map from [C programs] to [assembly programs], then is this map surjective?

**Caveat**: Of course, you can include assembly in C programs, but pretend that isn't possible (makes for a more interesting question!).

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn what types of questions are considered on-topic.

Comment: This seems to be asking "can you beat the compiler?".  The answer is almost always "yes".  C compilers are good, esp. at optimizing on a much larger scale than a human can mentally keep track of (multiple levels of inlining / simplification).  They're rarely optimal.  To beat the compiler, start with its output and look for places to save an instruction or use a better sequence of instructions, esp. in a loop.

Comment: How is this opinion based?  The question might be poor and off topic and but not for this reason.  If the question was: *Does `2+2` always equal `4` in C?*, would that be opinion based too?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question *If we think of "compiling" as a map from [C programs] to [assembly programs], then is this map surjective?* is obviously **NO**.

It can be proven trivially:
* There could be assembly language instructions that the compiler will not generate, such as `int 10`, `halt`, `jmp *eax`, `iret`, `sub esp,esp`...
* You might be fiddling with registers in assembly that the C compiler never touches, such as segment registers.

There is just a world of creativity in assembly that the C language cannot express.

Regarding the other question, I'm not sure what you mean by

> it is impossible to write, in any language besides C, a program that is faster than all variants in C, that do the same thing.

If you mean that a skilled programmer can always write a C program that will be faster at a given task than any other program written in any language, I think you probably wrong too, because the compiler itself is a fixed variable that is imperfect.

Imagine for example that the C compiler is very dumb and generates unoptimized code.  It is obvious that an assembly program can be written that will beat the best C variation at the given task: all that is needed is to optimize the unoptimized code.  Since the C compiler is imperfect, you can always find a task for which even the best C variation can be further optimized.

Comment: @DjangoProblems: if this answer is useful, would you please click the grey check mark below the answer score to accept it?